# Php not receiving data from form

Tags: php, sql, html, forms

I have a excerpt of my form, as follows:

```
// If logged in shows this box (it's backed behind a include php file that makes the login check

<form action="./saveList.php" method="post" id="ListaComprasForm">
<div class="submitButtonEncap">
  <button type="submit" method="POST" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary roundedBorder" form="ListaComprasForm" value="submit">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span> Save List
  </button>
</div>

<input type="text" id="Limpeza0" name="Limpeza[]" class="listInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_0" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>

<input type="text" id="Limpeza1" name="Limpeza[]" class="listInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_1" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>

<input type="text" id="Limpeza2" name="Limpeza[]" class="listInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_2" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>

<input type="text" id="Limpeza3" name="Limpeza[]" class="listInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_3" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>

<input type="text" id="Limpeza4" name="Limpeza[]" class="listInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_4" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>

<input type="text" id="Limpeza5" name="Limpeza[]" class="listInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_5" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>

<input type="text" id="Limpeza6" name="Limpeza[]" class="listInput" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50">
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_6" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>

</form>
```

This form, on submit, will submit to a DB wether or not checkboxes and TextBox fields have been filled or not. The checkboxes that have been checked or not, he'll submit them over as `Y` and `N` or `nullo` for the Textboxes respectively through some sorting code as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])){

    $L_chck[] = array();
    $H_chck[] = array();
    $V_chck[] = array();
    $F_chck[] = array();
    $Cong_chck[] = array();
    $Cons_chck[] = array();
    $Outros_chck[] = array();

    $Outros = array();

    for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 6; $counter++){
        $L_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['L_checkb_'.$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');
        $H_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['H_checkb_'.$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');
        $V_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['V_chckb_'.$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');
        $F_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['F_chckb_'.$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');
        $Cong_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['Cong_chckb_'.$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');
        $Cons_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['Cons_chckb_'.$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');
        $Outros_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['Outros_chckb_'.$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');

    if (empty($_POST['Outros'.$counter])) {
            $Outros[$counter] = $_POST['Outros'.$counter] = 'nullo';
        } else {
        $Outros[$counter] = $_POST['Outros'.$counter];
        }

    }


for ($i=0; $i <= 4; $i++) { 
        /*if ((isset($_POST['Limpeza'.$i])) == false) {*/
        if (empty($_POST['Limpeza'.$i])) {
            $Limpeza[$i] = $_POST['Limpeza'.$i] = 'nullo';
        } else {
            $Limpeza[$i] = $_POST['Limpeza'.$i];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['Higiene'.$i])) {
            $Higiene[$i] = $_POST['Higiene'.$i] = 'nullo';
        } else {
            $Higiene[$i] = $_POST['Higiene'.$i];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['Vegetais'.$i])) {
            $Vegetais[$i] = $_POST['Vegetais'.$i] = 'nullo';
        } else {
            $Vegetais[$i] = $_POST['Vegetais'.$i];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['Fruta'.$i])) {
            $Fruta[$i] = $_POST['Fruta'.$i] = 'nullo';
        } else {
            $Fruta[$i] = $_POST['Fruta'.$i];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['Congelados'.$i])) {
            $Congelados[$i] = $_POST['Congelados'.$i] = 'nullo';
        } else {
            $Congelados[$i] = $_POST['Congelados'.$i];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['Conservas'.$i])) {
            $Conservas[$i] = $_POST['Conservas'.$i] = 'nullo';
        } else {
            $Conservas[$i] = $_POST['Conservas'.$i];
        }
    }
```

This data is then passed on as arguments to a function to be serialized and sent to DB fields, all of them varchar(255):

```
 savingListData($L_chck, $H_chck, $V_chck, $F_chck, $Cong_chck, $Cons_chck, $Outros_chck, $Limpeza, $Higiene, $Vegetais, $Fruta, $Congelados, $Conservas, $Outros);
```

So far, every piece of data, being it checked/filled or not, it transposes over to the DB as null. In the case of the checkboxes, `N`, and in the case of the Textboxes `nullo`.

I'm led to believe that something is wrong in the sorting but I'm puzzled and can't figure out why. Would really appreciate some help!!

EDIT: Added more of the form in a shortened manner. (It's a big form!)

Comment: The name of the checkboxes is simply `L_checkb_[]` rather than `L_checkb_1` etc - the ID is never sent ~ so presumably the same applies to the other checkbox groups.

Comment: Can we have a sit down and talk about your naming conventions....

Comment: could you add the complete form?

Comment: @RamRaider Just tried that too and the problem still persists! I've also tried `L_checkb_[0]` and so on.

Comment: @RamRaider Added more of the form. Since the form is so big, I decided to trim it to the important parts, disregarding styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to retrieving it using wrong name. Its `L_chckb_[]`

```
<input type="checkbox" class="x" id="L_chck_0" name="L_chckb_[]" value="check"/>
```

So you need to use the loop counter outside the name key like this:

```
$L_chck[$counter] = (isset($_POST['L_chckb_'][$counter]) ? 'Y' : 'N');
```

The problem is: the name attribute in the tag is `L_chckb_` but you are trying to retrieve it by `L_checkb_` so that is the issue.

Because `L_checkb_` is not set and so it is giving you `N`.

Comment: I've just tried it and it's still passing on `N` and `nullo`.

Comment: @Incomplentence, check out my updated answer. Actually the input tag name attribute and the attribute you are trying to check with isset() do not match.

Comment: Naming is the bane of my existance in programming. It works now. I only named the indexes in the input so the order stays relevant. Thank you. Marking as answer.